# How to define a property function on getter property?

Tags: javascript, getter-setter

Is there a way to add a property on a getter function?

Ideally, the code I want to write is:

```js
const obj = {
  log: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
  get latest() {
    return this.log[this.log.length - 1];
  }
};

obj.latest.test = () => 123;

console.log(obj.latest);
// expected output: "c"
console.log(obj.latest.test())
// expect output: 123
```

My actual desire is this:
since my getter perform a pretty huge computation, for instance:

```
const obj = {
  otherproperties: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
  get items() {
    // VERY HUGE COMPUTATION...
    return [item0, item1, item2, item3]
  }
};
```

and sometimes I need only an element from the result, I want to write something:

```
obj.items.withId = (id) => {
  // Don't run the entire huge computation but..
  return computeOnlyId(id);
}
```

so to be able to write `obj.items` if I want all the values, or `obk.items.withId(1)` if I want only a specific item.

Probably, editing this question, I already understood that this is impossible since `items` it's a getter but I leave to you the keyboards for the answers.

What I would like to avoid is to have to write `obj.items.all()` to get all of them and `obj.items.withId(id)` to get only once.

Comment: If your getter returns something to which you can attach a property, of course. And you have to implement the property correctly. You've added a function, so you'd have to call it as such (`console.log(obj.latest.test());`)

Comment: The question is, what are you trying to accomplish? As [@Quentin notes in their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73022392/215552), you're returning a primitive value, so there isn't much use in adding a property to it. Also, adding properties after you've already gotten the value (rather than to the type of value returned) means those properties are only attached to the returned instance. The more context you can give us, the better answers we can provide.

Comment: Updated with some more context

Comment: The problem is that calling `obj.items` calls the getter. Once the getter returns, then it calls `withId(id)`, so you haven't saved yourself the compute time. You're better off with `object.itemsWithId(id)` and `object.items`, although I'm a proponent of putting anything that takes that much effort behind a method call, so `object.getItems()` and `object.getItemsWithId(id)` or just `object.getItems(id)`.

Comment: I agree with you. Unfortunately the getter is already there, that was my last chance to create a more ergonomic API but I think I'll go with a getItemsWithId method as you proposed.

Answer (score 0):

`obj.latest` is going to be the result of `this.log[this.log.length - 1]` which is going to be `'c'`.

Since `'c'` is a primitive, you can't (usefully) assign properties to it.

Comment: Oooh, right! That's was the missing part! I was returning a primitive value..